# onCreate method is called after calling onConfigurationChanged method in an Activity class

Tags: java, android

I am a beginner in android programming, now i am working on an android application which displays the data in a sort order by default and also provides a search facility. For this i have written an activity called search that will search the contents and displays in a listview. My problem is when i rotate the device the onCreate method of the Activity class is called even after overridding the onConfigurationChanged method. I had also done the following changes in the manifest file to invoke the onConfigurationChanged method.

```
<activity
    android:name=".Search"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
    android:screenOrientation="sensor" >
</activity>
```

My Search Activity is as follows :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  System.out.println("HERE AT ONCREATE");
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    System.out.println("HERE AT ON CONFIGURATION CHANGED");
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        setContentView(R.layout.search_port);
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        setContentView(R.layout.search_land);
    }
}
```

So the output while rotating the device will be :

1. HERE AT ON CONFIGURATION CHANGED
2. HERE AT ONCREATE

I dont want to get the `onCreate()` method called while rotating the device. Please help me to solve this issue. I am using Android 2.2 SDK with Samsung Galaxy Tab (7 inch display).

Comment: What is your target API version in manifest file. Did you check this link? If target is 13 or higher, it seems you need "screensize"  also http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

Comment: @thinksteep i am not sure what i am doing wrong, while debugging i could see the onConfigurationChanged method is invoked later it again calls the onCreate method of that activity. I think its strange.

Comment: Did you try this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

Comment: @thinksteep thanks for the link. I used onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() method and retained my data. The other way didnt worked. One more thing.. if you put this as answer i will accept it :) just kidding.. :)

Comment: Add yours as answer and accept it. That way next time when someone need it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to accomplish with the above code can be done much more simply.

If you change your layout files name to be both the same: `search_layout.xml` and place them in your project this way :

```
<project>/res/layout/search_layout.xml       // Portrait Layout
<project>/res/layout-land/search_layout.xml  // Landscape Layout
```

And then modify your Activity this way :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.i("Search Activity", "onCreate() was called.");
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    Log.i("Search Activity", "onConfigurationChanged was called.");
}
```

That's how I have it setup in my Activity and the `onCreate()` method is only called once.

Comment: thanks for your answer, even if use the xml file layout with same name, my problem the onCreate method doesnot ends, i need to do some initializations, in the starting of the activity. But it doesnot recreate or reinitialize the same things while changing the orientation of the device.

Answer (score -4):

There is no way to avoid it.  When you rotate your device, your Activity is killed and re-created.  There is no way to avoid it, but you can override onSaveInstanceState(), which will be called before the activity is destroyed.

Comment: configChanges in manifest file itself allow you to avoid calling onCreate (re-create). Read this link properly. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ConfigurationChanges

Comment: It is a wrong answer. You can declare configChanges in manifest file of the acitivity and that way this will not recreate the activity