# What is called after "onConfigurationChanged()"?

Tags: android, events, configuration, rotation, simulate

I am a young developer on Android and I can't find a solution to my problem.

I want to simulate an event just after the configuration changes and for that I have tried to use `onConfigurationChanged()` but with this method, my event is applied just before the screen rotates. But I want to apply my event just after the rotation.

So, how I can make it? Or what method is called after `onConfigurationChanged()`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10231323/oncreate-method-is-called-after-calling-onconfigurationchanged-method-in-an-acti

Answer (score 2):

Simple >>
Oncreate() method Called after onConfigurationChanged .

Comment: Thanks, but it's not working for me ... I already tried ... onCreate is working at launch of application, but it's not called after rotation :\

Comment: Check this > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10231323/oncreate-method-is-called-after-calling-onconfigurationchanged-method-in-an-acti. you will get your answer

Comment: Sorry I don't found answer in your URL :-\

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10231323/oncreate-method-is-called-after-calling-onconfigurationchanged-method-in-an-acti

Comment: Thanks Nirav, but I don't found answer.